# dropbox and proxy settings

Tags: proxy, dropbox

I have a Dropbox client (Windows) running on a network where a proxy can be detected but is not necessary.

Dropbox detects the proxy and configures it automatically (the client is then non-working). If I open the preferences (of dropbox) and disable the proxy then Dropbox is able to connect and starts working.

At the next restart the settings are lost. How can I force Dropbox **not** to use the proxy?

Comment: I notice this happens with me every time I open Dropbox with the Import Photos. I know I set it to Import Photos & Videos, but it seems to revert back after I restart the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Start > Startup
- Right click on Dropbox and select Properties
- Check on the box that says run as administrator

[image]

Comment: I don't have admin privileges on the machine, does this mean that Dropwork works in a non-privileged account but is not able to store the settings?

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of security policy the admin has set on the workstation.

Comment: Running it with admin privileges solved the problem. Should not be necessary (in my opinion) and will try to submit a bug report.

Comment: I think it is a bug too. It didn't happen before...

Comment: I submitted it to Dropbox ...